# SUMIFs Project Stages by Unique ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to run a SUMIFs in Excel where I have:

1. A list of Project, each with its own unique ID.
2. Each project has many stages, 1-99
3. We are tracking the number of days spent in each stage

I need to Sum the number of Days spent in each stage, by unique Project ID. Currently, I can sum everything by Stage number and Unique ID, but this formula returns values for each line item:

`=SUMIFS(N:N,M:M,M112,B:B,B112)`

So for each Stage 3, I will have the same summed total. Other than manually going through the sheet and deleting redundant values, how can I make it so the SUMIF only pulls values once per Unique ID, Stage Number?

Example:

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include some mock data and expected output, preferably in text(non photo) version so we can copy paste.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.